# Executing Stored Procedure with Table Value Parameters using Microsoft Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

I need to execute a stored procedure which contains a table-valued parameter (TVP) from Microsoft Excel. I can execute the procedure just fine using SQL Server Management Server:

```
DECLARE @CodProjTVP AS CodProjType;

INSERT INTO @CodProjTVP (CodProj)
    VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);

EXEC SPAcomAtividades '2015-01-01', '2015-02-01', @CodProjTVP;
```

And it returns what I'm expecting... But when I try to execute it from Excel, I get a (very generic) error. I suspect that there is some issue with the declaration of the TVP, but I don't usually work with Excel and would love some guidance.

Is there any way to check what went wrong? Is there a simple solution to this?

Thanks.

Comment: Which error? How do you call the Proc? Can you show the VBA code?

Comment: So far I haven't been using VBA, because all I needed was executing simple stored procedures. I just used the SQL Connection Helper built into Excel. Quite honestly I didn't even know how to start to go about this. Is VBA the way to go?

Comment: Oh I see. Well, I'm always using pure VBA for calling stored procs, so I can't say much about the Connection Helper. Calling a stored proc in VBA is easy, but passing a TVP is for sure a little more complex.

Comment: Well, I'm guessing that VBA should be the way to go about this, but I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on how to go about it.